# How to throw Exception when SharedFlow does not contain item

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-sharedflow

I need to check that SharedFlow contain some item.
And throw NoSuchElementException when this element is absent.

I'm writed some code below, it work perfect when SharedFlow contain item.
But if this element is absent code just waiting all the time.

```
private val _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

// fill _sharedFlow with some states
private suspend fun emitStates() {
    _sharedFlow.emit("START")
    delay(100)
    _sharedFlow.emit("FIRST")
    delay(100)
    _sharedFlow.emit("SECOND")
    delay(100)
    _sharedFlow.emit("ENDING")
    delay(100)
    _sharedFlow.emit("IDLE")
}


private suspend fun awaitState(state: String) {
    _sharedFlow.filter {
                incomingState -> incomingState == state
            }
            .onCompletion {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion()")
            }
            .onEmpty {
                Log.d(TAG, "onEmpty()")
            }
            .firstOrNull()
}
```

RUN PROGRAM WITH SUCCESS:

```
private suspend fun waitSecond() {
    // waiting for "SECOND"
    awaitState("SECOND")
    // run other code after getting "SECOND"
}
```

RUN PROGRAM WITH FAILED:

```
private suspend fun waitSomeString() {
    try {
        // waiting for "Some" all the time
        awaitState("Some")
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        // catch NoSuchElementException 
        // run other code after Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t conceptually make sense for a hot flow. It’s always possible that a hot flow may emit an item at some future time so it’s impossible to check if the flow “does not contain” an item. Also your code currently doesn’t have any buffer in the SharedFlow so a collector could easily be missing past emitted items. You can check if it emits an item within a certain amount of time. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your `onCompletion` and `onEmpty` code can never run because a SharedFlow never completes.

Comment: @Tenfour04, you are right. In my real code I'm use `MutableSharedFlow(replay = Int.MAX_VALUE)`, so subscribers doesn't miss an emit(). Thank you a lot for your opinion. Now I'm solve it with workaround  `withTimeout()`

Comment: BTW, we can get List of current items with `_sharedFlow.replayCache`